# Selenium(Python) click add to cart button not working!Have searched up and down and can't find anything

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I have been working on a way to click the add to cart button using Selenium on a website and have run into troubles.The page opens up and brings me to the page I need, but doesn't click the button. I have tried all the find_element_'s and none of them seem to work my code right now is:

```
def add_to_cart(url):
    driver.get(url)
    elem=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#add-remove-buttons > input')
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    actions.click(elem)
```

HTML code for the Button element

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="add to cart" class="button">
```

Thank you!

Comment: <input type="submit" name="commit" value="add to cart" class="button">

Comment: Have you tried adding some wait for the element to load

Answer (score 0):

The element is either not visible to Webdriver, being refreshed by the site and your code performs the click before the element has reloaded, or the element is covered by an overlay. I'm sure you would have seen an overlay while inspecting the button, though. Try adding a wait time for the button to be clickable like in `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CSS_SELECTOR, elem)`, or visible/presence located through `WebDriverWait`. You can maybe use `actions` like

```
actions = Actionchains(driver) 
actions.move_to_element(elem).perform().click()
```